# A git-gui dying because of "bad pad value"

Tags: git

Since today, I'm starting to get

```
bgerror failed to handle background error.
    Original error: bad pad value "3m": must be positive screen distance
    Error in bgerror: bad pad value "3m": must be positive screen distance
```

from `git gui`. It doesn't depend on the repository and happens rather often. After the error, the window is practically dead.

I guess, it came in with a recent update.

Any idea?

---

```
git-gui version 0.20.0
Linux ... 4.4.0-127-generic #153-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 19 10:58:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the answer](https://kubos.cz/2016/11/07/git-gui-error-when-opening-dialogs.html): The reason was bogus DPI, using

```
xrandr --dpi 96
```

fixed it.